# Different formats of geo_point type?

Tags: java, lucene, geolocation, elasticsearch

From the documentation here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/geo-point-type.html

It says geo_point accept different format. Ex: these two are supported

> 1. "location" : "-71.34, 41.12"
> 2. "location" : {
>              "lat" : 41.12,
>              "lon" : -71.34
>      }

I want to ask if these two are the same?
I'm using ES 0.17.6 and having this problem:

When I index using the (1) format, I can't search with (2) format. If
I use (1) format to search again, it is successful.

For example:
If I index with (2) format:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/pin/1' -d '
{
    "pin" : {
        "location" : {
                        lat: 41.12,
                        lon: -71.34
                },
        "tag" : ["food", "family"],
        "text" : "my favorite family restaurant"
    }
}'
```

I can't search with this (1) format

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/pin/_search' -d '
{
        "query": {
                "filtered" : {
                        "query" : {
                                "field" : { "text" : "restaurant" }
                        },
                        "filter" : {
                                "geo_distance" : {
                                        "distance" : "12km",
                                        "pin.location" : "-71.34, 41.12"
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
}
'
```

And it will be successful if I search using (2) format:

```
2. "pin.location" : {
            "lat" : 41.12,
            "lon" : -71.34
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When geo_point is represented as a string, it should follow `lat lon` format: `"pin.location" : "41.12, -71.34"`